# Service Locator vs Constructor injection performance

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, dependency-injection

It is considered that the Service Locator is an antipattern. But is it correct to get all the necessary dependencies in the constructor if they are used only under certain conditions?

**Approach 1 (Service Locator)**

```
public class MyType
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        if (someRareCondition1)
        {
            var dep1 = Locator.Resolve<IDep1>();
            dep1.DoSomething();
        }

        if (someRareCondition2)
        {
            var dep2 = Locator.Resolve<IDep2>();
            dep2.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2 (Constructor injection)**

```
public class MyType
{
    private readonly IDep1 dep1;
    private readonly IDep2 dep2;

    public MyType(IDep1 dep1, IDep2 dep2)
    {
        this.dep1 = dep1;
        this.dep2 = dep2;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        if (someRareCondition1)
        {
            dep1.DoSomething();
        }

        if (someRareCondition2)
        {
            dep2.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

You can have many different voids that need different dependencies, but only in certain cases. Is it better to use a Service Locator for performance & memory?

Comment: `Lazy<Dependency>` - https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html . Short answer - it is _incredibly_ rare that Service Locator is preferable.

Comment: Yes, I would say it's correct to take both dependencies. You could also abstract the condition out of the method and into some strategy pattern so you only take 1 dependency, but that dependency knows what to do depending on `someRareConditionN`.

Comment: Object construction should be lightweight and fast, therefore, even if your constructor requires an object that is not used, that shouldn't affect the performance.

Comment: Inject one factory. The factory will create the desired type on demand.

Comment: Apart from performance, dependencies injected via constructor makes it easier to unit test the class using mocked dependencies. It is not required to map mocks in ServiceLocator if you use constructor dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before I'll talk about the performance difference between the two approaches, I need to set the stage and talk about the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/), because not every callback to the DI Container is an implementation of Service Locator.

Calls to the DI Container (or an abstraction over it) should be prevented from application code, e.g. inside your MVC controllers, or code part of your business layer. Callbacks from these parts of your code base can be considered examples of Service Locator.

Callbacks from parts of your application's *startup path*, a.k.a. the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), on the other hand, are *not* considered to be Service Locator implementations. That's because the Service Locator pattern is more than the mechanical description of a Resolve API, but rather a description of [the *role* it plays](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) in your application. These calls to the Container from *inside* the Composition Root are fine, beneficial, or even required for your application to function. Therefore, for the remaining part of my answer, I rather refer to "callback to the DI Container" rather than "using the Service Locator pattern."

When it comes to performance, there are many things to consider. It would be impossible for me to mention every possible performance bottleneck and tweak, but I'll mention the few things I think are most worthwhile to talk about in the context of your question.

Whether or not the lazy resolving of dependencies by calling back into the container is faster than constructor injection depends on a lot of factors. In general, I would say that in both cases performance is typically irrelevant as object composition would unlikely be your application's performance bottleneck. In most cases I/O takes up the bulk of the time. Time is typically better spent in optimizing I/O—it results in better performance gains with less investments.

That said, one thing to realize is that DI Containers are typically highly optimized and can do optimizations during compilation of the generated code that composes your application's object graphs. But these optimizations are thrown out when you start to break up object graphs by calling back into the container lazily. This makes constructor injection a more optimized approach, compared to breaking an object graph in pieces and resolving them one by one.

If I use Simple Injector—the DI Container that I maintain—as an example, it does quite aggressive optimizations on generated Expression trees before it starts compiling them. Those optimizations include:

- Reducing size of compiled code by reusing compiled code within the graph.
- Optimizing the request of scoped components within the graph, by caching them in variables (closures) inside the compiled method. This prevents duplicate dictionary look-ups.

Your mileage will obviously vary, but most DI Containers perform some kind of optimization. I'm unsure what kinds of optimizations the built-in ASP.NET Core DI Container applies though, but AFAIK its optimizations are limited.

There is overhead in calling your Container's `Resolve` method. At the very least it causes a dictionary lookup from the requested type to the code that is able compose the graph for that type, while dictionary look-ups tend not to happen (that much) for resolved dependencies. But in practice calls to `Resolve` tend to have some validity checks and other required logic that adds overhead to such call. This is another reason why constructor injection a more optimized approach, compared to doing callbacks.

Modern DI Containers are usually optimized so they can resolve big object graphs with ease (although with some containers there is a limit in the size of the object graph, although that limit is typically pretty big). Their overhead compared to creating those same object graphs manually (using plain old C#) is usually minimal (although differences and exceptions exist). But this only works if you follow the best practice to [keep your injection constructors simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). When injection constructors are simple, it doesn't matter if you inject dependencies that are only used part of the time.

When you fail to follow this best practice, for instance by having injection constructors that callback to the database or perform some logging to disk, performance of object graph resolution can slow down considerably. This can be certainly painful when you're dealing with components that aren't always used. This seems to be the context of your question. Here's an example of a problematic injection constructor:

```cs
// This Injection Constructor does more than just receiving its dependencies.
public OrderShippingService(
    ILogger logger, IConfigurationProvider provider)
{
    // Storing the incoming dependency; this is fine.
    this.logger = logger;

    // Here it starts using its dependencies; this is problematic.
    logger.LogInfo("Creating OrderShippingService.");
    this.config = provider.Load<OrderShippingServiceConfig>();
    logger.LogInfo("OrderShippingService Config loaded.");
}
```

My advise, therefore, is: follow the "simple injection constructors" best practice and make sure that injection constructors do no more than receive and store their incoming dependencies. Do not use dependencies from inside the constructor. This practice also helps when dealing with dependencies that are only used part of the time, because when those dependencies are fast to create, the problem goes away and using constructor injection will typically still be faster compared to doing callbacks.

On top of that, there are other best practices that should be followed, such as the [Single-Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Following it prevents constructors to get many dependencies and prevents the Constructor Over-Injection code smell. Object graphs that contain classes with many dependencies tend to become much bigger in size and, therefore, slower to resolve. This best practice doesn't help when dealing with those sometimes-used dependencies, though.

It might be the case, however, that you're unable to refactor such slow constructor, which requires you to prevent it to be eagerly loaded. But there are other cases in which eager loading can cause problems. That can happen, for instance, when your application uses [Composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) or [Mediators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Composites and Mediators typically wrap many components and can forward an incoming call to a limited subset of them. Especially a Mediator, which typically forwards the call to a single component. For instance:

```cs
// Component using a mediator abstraction.
public class ShipmentController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;
    
    public void ShipOrder(ShipOrderCommand cmd) =>
        mediator.Execute(cmd);
    
    public void CancelOrder(CancelOrderCommand cmd) =>
        mediator.Execute(cmd);
}
```

In the code above, the `IMediator` implementation should forward the `Execute` call to a component that knows how to handle the supplied command. In this example the `ShipmentController` forwards two different command types to the mediator.

Even with simple injection constructors, the previous example might cause performance problems when the application contains hundreds of those 'handlers' in case those handlers contain deep object graphs by themselves and are all recreated each time `ShipmentController` is composed.

The following implementation demonstrates these performance issues:

```
// I'm using C# 9 record type syntax here, because that makes the example succinct
record Mediator(IHandler[] Handlers) : IMediator
{
    public void Execute<T>(T command) =>
        Handlers.OfType<IHandler<T>>().Single().Execute(command);
    }
}
```

In this example, all handlers are eagerly created before `Mediator` is, and injected into the `Mediator`'s constructor, while a call to `Execute` just picks one from the list. This could lead to performance issues when there are many handlers that contain many dependencies of their own. This is because in order to execute one handler, all handlers with their dependencies need to be constructed. Not ideal.

To prevent this performance problem, calling back into the DI Container is an option to consider. It doesn't require the Service Locator anti-pattern, though, because the `Mediator` implementation (and, therefore, the callback) should reside *inside* your Composition Root. A possible `IMediator` implementation could look like this:

```cs
// As long as this implementation is placed inside the Composition Root,
// this is -not- an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern.
record Mediator(IServiceProvider Container) : IMediator
{
    public void Execute<T>(T cmd) =>
        Container.GetService<IHandler<T>>().Execute(cmd);
}
```

In this case, only the relevant handler is requested from the DI Container—not all of them. This means that the DI Container at this point, only creates the object graph for that particular handler.

In all cases, however, you should prevent calling back to the DI Container from *within* application code. I would even argue not to inject a `Lazy<T>` for a conditionally used dependency, even though some DI Containers have support for this. This only complicates the consumer's code, its tests, and makes it easy to forget to apply `Lazy<T>` to all constructors for that dependency.

Instead, creating a Proxy would be a better approach. That proxy would live inside the Composition Root and would either wrap a `Lazy<T>` or call back into the Container:

```cs
record DelayedDependencyProxy(IServiceProvider Container) : IDependency
{
    private IDependency real;
    
    public object SomeMethod()
    {
        if (real is null)
            real = Container.GetService<RealDependency>();
        
        return real.SomeMethod();
    }    
}
```

This Proxy keeps the consumers of `IDependency` clean and oblivious to the use of any mechanism to delay the creation of the dependency. Instead of injecting `RealDependency` into consumers of `IDependency`, you now inject `DelayedDependencyProxy`.

One last, but important note: do prevent premature optimizations. Prefer constructor injection over container callbacks even if container callbacks are faster. If you suspect any performance bottlenecks by constructor injection: measure, measure, measure. And do verify if the bottleneck really is in object composition itself, or in the constructor of one of your components. And if fixed, verify that this gives a performance boost significant enough to justify the increased complexity it causes. A performance win of 1 millisecond is not significant for most applications.

Comment: In addition to this: When object construction happens to be that expensive that you need to consider resolving the dependency lazily (which is already something you should avoid, as Steven mentioned), then consider re-evaluating the lifetime of your (expensive) components: Previously constructed singletons for example can be resolved pretty much instantly, so you don't need to worry about them being resolved via constructor injection even though you might not need them.

Comment: Great addition @poke. Performance can be managed using Lifetime Management.